# how to improve insert into select Waiting for table behaviour

Tags: mysql, select, insert, locking, innodb

our database is full innoDB,
it is accessed by many systemes, some of them launch a stored procedure wich behave something like that :

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `fooBar`()
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_hugeTable LIKE hugeTable;  
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary__listeId  LIKE fooHugeTableToo;  
INSERT INTO temporary__listeId   SELECT id  FROM   fooHugeTableToo;
INSERT INTO temporary_hugeTable
        SELECT distinct bla, blah, blahh 
        FROM hugeTable
        INNER JOIN temporary__listeId ON temporary__listeId.id =  hugeTable_id
COMMIT;
END
```

if a **few query** run at the same time, it's ok, but when **many queries** run simultaneously, it result in a insert stack lasting a loooong time (1 hour?).

Where one of the query has the the *INSERT INTO temporary_bar SELECT* stuck in the *"Sending data"* state and all the others are stucked in the *"Waiting for table"* state.

Whe use innoDB, we have putted the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED, I don't know what to do more.

NB : we are using mysql 5.0, maybe the solution is there (updating to a recent version)
NB2 : the server has only 4Go or RAM and I think that it is swapping a lot whene to much temporary tables are in use

Comment: Why do you need the temp tables?  There may be a way to solve the _real_ problem without fixing the current problem.

Comment: the temp table is a "legacy" feature : an old and obsolete soft use them in order to read partial data of the huges tables. Removing them is a pain in the ass because nobody can modifie the soft needing them...
A month ago whe moved from myisam to innodb and the last issue we are experiencing is those stored pocedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `fooBar`()
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
START TRANSACTION;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary__listeId   SELECT id  FROM   fooHugeTableToo;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_hugeTable 
SELECT distinct bla, blah, blahh 
FROM hugeTable
INNER JOIN temporary__listeId ON temporary__listeId.id =  hugeTable_id
COMMIT;
END
```

through this you not need to write `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_hugeTable LIKE hugeTable;` what happen through select statement all caloumns are created automatically those who are in select query

Comment: Sorry, but, I don't understand your answer : since the lock is related to the INSERT ...  SELECT,
how does your solution prevent the lock to appear?